# non-fast-forward error in git

Tags: git, version-control, github, git-pull

I want to use **git** in my existing project, so I created a space on **github** for it and in the project folder on my host I did the usual:

```
$ git config --global user.name myname
$ git config --global user.email "myemail@email.com"
$ cd myProjectFolder/
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "first commit"
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/myusername/myprojectname.git
```

And then I want all the files of my project to be also on the online repository:

```
$ git push origin master
```

But I got the following much-dreaded error:

```
To https://github.com/myusername/myprojectname.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/myusername/myprojectname.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Now, there is nothing I have to `pull` from the online repository, since there is still nothing over there. Why should I pull?

Anyhow, what exactly should I do here to have all my files online and start using git?

Comment: Do a `git fetch --all`: when you created your github repo, didn't you tell it, by any chance, to add a README or something?

Comment: ...which if you did means that your GitHub repository has commits that are not yet in your local repository.  Running `git pull` as the error suggests will bring your local repository up to date, at which time ou can `push`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `git remote add`, the URL of teh remote repo is known in yours but not yet it's content.

After `git fetch origin` (or `git pull`), you'll be able to `git push` since **then** the content of the remote repo will be known.

Comment: Nope. I did as you said (`git fetch origin` and `git push`) and I still got the same error as above. What went wrong?